# HTTPRequest with multiple parameters

Tags: syntax, web-access

Want to use the API from [this site](http://sbml.org/Facilities/Documentation/Validator_Web_API).
I'm having trouble using the same parameters.

But I can do this with curl as shown on the site:

```
curl 
  -F url=http://sbml.org/validator/api/sample-01.xml 
  -F output=xml 
  -F offcheck=u 
  http://sbml.org/validator/
```

But I can't get the same with Mathematica:

```
t1 = URLExecute @ HTTPRequest[
  "http://sbml.org/validator/"
, <|"Method" -> "POST"
  , "Headers" -> {
      "Content-Type" -> "multipart/form-data;"
    , "Expect" -> ""
    }
  , "MultipartElements" -> {
      {"name=\"url\";"} -> "http://sbml.org/validator/api/sample-01.xml"}
  |>
, CharacterEncoding -> None
];

ImportString[StringJoin[t1], "XHTML"]
```

OUTPUT

```
File : null
Options :
Units consistency checking: on Identifier consistency checking: on \
MathML consistency checking: on SBO consistency checking: on \
Overdetermined model checking: on Modeling practices checking: on \
Overall SBML consistency checking: on Remove unrecognized packages: \
on Results: No model was given or it could not be resolved.
```

Comment: Don't you need `apikey`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you will get a valid `apikey` you can use `x-www-form-urlencoded` and a list of rules in the body to send a form. I'm not sure how to handle `form-data` type:

```
t1 = URLExecute @ HTTPRequest[
   "http://sbml.org/validator/"
, <|"Method" -> "POST"
  , "Headers" -> {
      "Content-Type" -> "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    }
  , "Body" -> {
      "url" -> "http://sbml.org/validator/api/sample-01.xml"
    , "output" -> "xml"
    , "offcheck" -> "u"
    }
  |>
, CharacterEncoding -> None
]
```

> ```
> "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
>   <validation-results>
>     <not-authenticated/>
>   </validation-results>"
> ```

As you can see it works but you need to authenticate.

Comment: Thanks. I've been asking for a key but I'm not getting a reply. Was hoping to use it without key like in the curl example.

Comment: @MathProtein but they say you need api key just after the initial curl syntax example.

Comment: It works without it as well.